# Delete unused apk files from system memory

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, apk, system-apps

I own a Xperia M running on Jelly Bean 4.3. I have uninstalled unwanted apps like PicsArt, Cricbuzz, Xperia privilege and so many so on... a long time ago. Now I found the apk files of those apps here -
System memory/etc/customization/applications/
System memory/product/applications/
All the apps consume an amount of 250mb internal memory. I want to delete them all as I don't need them anyway. So is it safe to delete all the apk files?
Note: Device is not rooted so I don't have an option of moving applications to SD card. I want to free some memory so that I can download some more apps ;)

Comment: Deleting system apps won't help free up storage, since they're on the system partition, not the userdata partition.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it myself. I can't delete these files until I'm rooted.